# Can you save all the photos on the pokemon contest spectacular?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I want to save all not just one, can you?

Comment: You should try first....? Anyway, the last time I tried it it saved all of them (I own Omega Ruby).